# Does $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\iff$ $M_{X+Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)$ ? (where $M_X(t)$ is the moment generating function)

Tags: probability

If now that $X,Y$ are independent $\iff$ $\varphi _{X+Y}(t)=\varphi _X(t)\varphi _Y(t),$ where $\varphi _U(t):=\mathbb E[e^{itU}]$.

Let $M_U(t):=\mathbb E[e^{tU}]$. Do we still have $X$ and $Y$ are independents $\iff$ $$M_{X+Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)\ \ \ \ ?$$

I know that the implication is true, but what about the converse ?

Comment: One issue that $M_X$, $M_Y$ and $M_{X+Y}$ may exsit only for $t=0$, in which case the identity is trivial regardless of what $X$, $Y$ and $X+Y$ are.

Comment: Suppose that they exist for all $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement about characteristic function is not true. If $X$ has Cauchy distribution and $Y=X$ then $\phi_{X+Y} (t)=e^{-2|t|}=(e^{-|t|})^{2}=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)$ for  all $t$ though $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. What is true is the following: If $\phi_{aX+bY}(t)=\phi_X(at)\phi_Y(bt)$ for  all $a,b,t$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The corresponding result for moment generating function is also true.

Comment: Many thanks for your very good answer :)